# gnuplot - using line color as third variable does not generate the required output

Tags: plot, gnuplot

Using gnuplot, I am trying to make a 2D plot with points where the point color is represented by the third column of a data file(file has 3 columns)

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mxmwgg8jbtm0ton/outPhaseDiff_b1_dScan.dat?dl=0) is the link to the file

I am using the following command to generate the graph:

```
pl "outPhaseDiff_b1_dScan.dat" u 1:2:3 w p pt 7 ps 2 lc variable
```

The desired output should contain 5 colors but it is only plotting 2 colors, which is really strange because I have been using this command for a long time and did not encounter such issue before. I guess it has to do something with the plotting algorithm but I have no clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your data, it contains many line pairs with the following pattern:

```
0.0000   0.0060   3
0.0000   0.0060   5
```

One line with `x, y, color1`, another line with identical `x` and `y`, but different `color2`. So the points from the second line hide the points from the first one.

If you plot it 3d with several layers, it looks like this:

```
z = 0
y = 0
splot "outPhaseDiff_b1_dScan.dat" \
      u 1:2:($2 == y ? (z = z+1) : (z = 0, y=$2), z):3 \
      w p pt 7 ps 2 lc variable
```

[image: two layers]

A 2d `plot` looks from top, only two colors are visible.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this out ! Indeed that was the problem..Apparently, I had a bug in my code which generated duplicate values causing this to happen.